# Problemas com .htaccess pasta raiz e redirecionamento https

Tags: htaccess, https

Estou com um problema aqui, não tenho conhecimentos com `.htaccess` e não estou conseguindo configura-lo.

Eu preciso que ele redirecione o domínio sem *www* para o domínio com *www*, um erro é que está redirecionando todos os domínios *HTTPs* para `http://meusite.com/meusite.com` <-sem o "s" no fim do *HTTPs* e a pasta raiz não é a padrão, mas isto ocorre apenas quando digito para acessar *HTTPs*.

Enquanto o correto seria `https://meusite.com`, poderiam me passar os códigos para criar o arquivo `.htaccess`?

Preciso dos códigos com os dois itens que citei e no fim o código para redirecionamento de todas *URLs* para acessarem https para fazer alguns testes aqui.

Segue o meu código que não está funcionando:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^classificadosjs.com.br [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.classificadosjs.com.br/ [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^classificadosjs.com.br$ [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.classificadosjs.com.br$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/home/classif3/public_html/classificadosjs.com.br/
RewriteRule (.*) /home/classif3/public_html/classificadosjs.com.br/$1 [L]
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home/classif3/public_html/classificadosjs.com.br/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/classif3/public_html/classificadosjs.com.br/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www.classificadosjs.com.br [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.classificadosjs.com.br/$1 [R,L]
```

Obs.: Não sei se devo colocar `RewriteEngine off` no fim? No caso eu coloquei e não funcionou mais nada, desculpe sou muito sem conhecimento no assunto.